# Bcd subtractor units connections

Tags: adder, binary

I'm new in electronics.
I'm trying to make a BCD calculator, but I got stuck in BCD subtraction.
I got stuck in: how can I connect multiple bcd subtrator units?
I'm trying to make a 3 digit calculator, but this can only subtract 1 digit.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

PS: I've posted the circuit diagram below.

[image: The design I'm using]

Comment: You need a borrow input for more than one digit, same as you need a carry input for a BCD adder of more than one digit.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, but how can I implement a borrow input?

Comment: Good question. That would be more of an answer than a comment and I'll leave the fame and glory to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research I built a circuit diagram which should work.

PS: Every Input wire (a0,b0,a1,b1,a2,b2) stands for 1 decimal digit (4 wires)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGfWkZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>